# <select required="required"> not working for my code

Tags: html, xslt

I have this code in which i am using a drop-down. I have used required class to make it mandatory but it is not working. Does anyone can help me.My drop-down values is coming from local database.

`HTML`

```html
<select required="required" type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField(this)">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <xsl:for-each select="faml/response/qlwidgetresponsedto/searchby/datamapdto">
    <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="description" />
    <option value="#{description}">
      <xsl:value-of select="description" />
    </option>
  </xsl:for-each>
</select>
```

Comment: It seems to be working for me. What is the final HTML after the drop-down is populated?

Comment: Sorry i dont understand you?

Comment: I mean, after the `<option>` elements are added, how does the HTML look?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the selected [output method](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-HTML-Output-Method):

> The html output method should output boolean attributes (that is
>   attributes with only a single allowed value that is equal to the name
>   of the attribute) in minimized form. For example, a start-tag written
>   in the stylesheet as
>
> ```
> <OPTION selected="selected">
> ```
>
> should be output as
>
> ```
> <OPTION selected>
> ```

In XSLT 1.0 you might use `"xml"` output method. In XSLT 2.0+ you also have [`"xhtml"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xslt-xquery-serialization-20101214/#xhtml-output) output method.